# Mobile Couchbase for iPhone: Getting started

Tags: iphone, ios, nosql, couchdb, couchbase

Can someone demonstrate in a short code recipe how to use Couchbase Mobile for iPhone? If not, can you explain why it isn't that simple?

Comment: Here's a great [screencast](http://hexeditreality.com/content/add-couchdb-your-ios-application-5-minutes) that outlines how to include Couchbase/CouchDB into your iOS application.